# Ajax showing 403 with this parameter only on domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-status-code-403

I am using namecheap server hosting and issue is only arriving on server its working smoothly on localhost

http://www.nntech.website/ajax?Option=SaveUserReport&UserId=2&Query=SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE1 = 1 AND ScheduledBy LIKE '%rebe%' &QueryName=rebe&Type=UserReport

Comment: any help will be highly recommended please :(

Comment: @manikantgautam i am trying to make a customized view for users where they can sort the data according to their needs and save it as a view for themselves

Comment: thanku @manikantgautam how can i add headers ? any help ?

Comment: @manikantgautam when i am sending a query like this "select * from tablename where fieldname = 'this' " it workis like a charm but only generating error on like '%%' query

Comment: issue resolved :) encoded the variable data and worked fine :)